# Wpf - How to update or notify ObservableCollection in parent window when a new item is added in child window

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I want to update n notify my existing products list in parent window when I add a new product in child window.I have subscribed the Observable collection to NotifyPropertyChanged but still the list doesn't gets updated with the new product.I need to again fetch the whole list of products from the database to refresh it.

```
private ObservableCollection<Product>   _productsList;
public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductsList
{
       get {return _productsList ;}
        private set {
             _productsList = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductsList");
      }
}


 public void AddNewProduct()
 {
        Window_NewProduct newProduct = new Window_NewProduct();
        newProduct.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Please help me around.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged`when the whole `ProductsList` property has changed, not when you add or remove elements to/from that list. So I think you need to register an event handler for the `_productsList.CollectionChagned` event and call `NotifyPropertyChanged`from that event handler. But I'm not so experienced in wpf to know how `NotifyPropertyChanged` should be called for collections, so I don't post this as an answer.

Comment: Subscribe to `CollectionChanged` event of `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Can u please help me around with some code about the implementation of CollectionChanged

Answer (score 0):

Your `NotifyPropertyChanged` will get triggered when you replace your `ObservableCollection`. What you need is to register for the `CollectionChanged` events of your `ProductsList` Property. See: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the logic for adding new product do DB?
In Window_NewProduct ?

If so, the product is added to database but not to ProductsList. The problem here is no how to refresh ProductsList but to properly add new item to this list. You can try to return newly added Product from Window_NewProduct and add it to ProductsList. As it is ObservableCollection all refreshing should execute automatically.

Some pseudo code here:

```
public void AddNewProduct()
{
    Window_NewProduct newProductWindow = new Window_NewProduct();
    if(newProductWindow.ShowDialog() == OK)
    {
         ProductsList.Add(newProductWindow.NewlyAddedProduct);
    }

}
```

UPDATE 1:

It  is really hard to give you solution unless we do not know how Window_NewProduct looks like.
However, I can assume that you have there method similar to:

```
void SaveProduct()
{
  var product = new Product();
  Database.Save(product);
}
```

you can make it like:

```
public Product NewlyAddedProduct{get;private set;} //public property of Window

public void SaveProduct()
{
  var product = new Product();
  Database.Save(product);
  NewlyAddedProduct = product;
}
```

Comment: That function AddNewProduct is in the parent window and the logic for adding product to db is in the child window i.e Window_NewProduct.after adding new product to the database in child window.I want the products list in parent window to get updated with new item.

Comment: I did not get that NewlyAddedProduct thing you mentioned